# jQuery put dynamically created list inside <ul> tags

Tags: jquery, list, append

`.append()` does not seem to do the trick, it place both `<ul>`&`</ul>` at the the top.
how should I do it?

(The `fullQuestion` is only one `<li>` it is generated for avery question)

```
function writeQuestions() {

$('#container').append("<ul>\n");

len = questions.qestion.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        var answerRdy = [];
        var qestionRdy = questions.qestion[i];
        answerRdy[0] = questions.answer[i][0];
        answerRdy[1] = questions.answer[i][1];
        answerRdy[2] = questions.answer[i][2];
        answerRdy[3] = questions.answer[i][3];
        var divID = "question-" + i;
        var formID = "form-" + i;
        var CurrentForm = i;

            var writeAnswer = [];
            writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("\n<br />`<li id='{0}'>`\n<form id='{1}' name='{2}'>\n").format(divID, formID, CurrentForm);
            writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("<b>" + qestionRdy + "</b><br />\n");
        for (var n=0; n<=3; n++) {
            writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("<input type='radio' name='answerN' value='{0}' /> {1} <br />\n").format(n, answerRdy[n]);
                }
            writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("<input type='submit' value='Submit your answer'>\n</form>\n</li><!--{0}-->").format(divID);


        var joinQuestion = writeAnswer.join();
    //  var joinQuestion = "<ul>\n" + joinQuestion + "\n</ul>"
            exp = /,/gi;
        var fullQuestion = joinQuestion.replace(exp, "");

    $('#container').append(fullQuestion);
}

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var formID = document.forms["form-" + i];
    $(formID).bind("submit", validate);
}

$('#container').append("\n</ul>");
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use append properly.

Create a UL first

```
var $ul = $('<ul>');
$('#container').append($ul);
//all other code
$ul.append(fullQuestion);
```

And remove this line `$('#container').append("\n</ul>");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should insert the fullQuestion string inside the ul

$('#container ul').html(fullQuestion);